# PyFlink - Kafka - Missing module

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I am trying to start with PyFlink and Kafka, but get below error.

Thanks for your support !

**Installation**

```
python -m pip install apache-flink
pip install pyFlink
```

**Code**

```
from pyFlink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
```

**Error**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyFlink'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install PyFlink, you only need to execute:

`python -m pip install apache-flink`

and make sure you have a compatible Python version (>= 3.5).

Imports are case-sensitive; the error is thrown because the package name is "pyflink", not "pyFlink". So, instead, you can try:

`from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment`

If you're going to use Kafka, please remember to also add the [required (JAR) dependencies](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/connectors/kafka.html#dependencies), using:

```py
config = t_env.get_config().get_configuration()
config.set_string("pipeline.jars",
                  "file:///path/to/jar/jarfile.jar")
```

You can read more about handling connectors and other dependencies in the [PyFlink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/python/table-api-users-guide/dependency_management.html).

Comment: Thanks Marta ! This helps starting up.

Comment: My comment about installing and starting Kafka/Zookeeper first might sound trivial, but is likely not straightforward for newbies.

Comment: It's for sure relevant for beginners, @py-r. I just don't think it should be part of the answer since it's not Flink-related.